# Javascript control program flow when you can't modify async function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

So all the examples I've seen with promises or callbacks usually involve injecting the callback into the asynchronous function inside of the setTimeout or something like that. But what if you have a function that you can't modify for whatever reason. Maybe it's imported from a library, idk. Imagine this code.

```
const funcA = () => {
    setTimeout(() =>console.log("first"), 500)
            
}

const funcB = () => {
    console.log("second");
}

funcA();
funcB();
```

How do you get second to print after first, without modifying funcA?

Comment: There's no *good* way. The library's `funcA` can be considered to be effectively broken. Submit a bug report and fix it if you can.

Comment: Oh I see. I thought maybe I was misunderstanding something about how asynchronous code works in js, but I guess you really do need to inject code INSIDE of the asynchronous function. Thanks

Comment: If the function is not designed properly - if it doesn't take a callback or return a Promise - yeah, changing its contents is the only decent way to get around it.

Comment: Thanks. Well I guess that's case closed.

Comment: Do you know what sequential order means ?

Comment: Yeah, I know what it means

Comment: All async functions in javascript either return a promise or accept a callback. This has been the culture in javascript since the mid 2000s. If you ever encounter the situation in your question the **best** solution is to not use that library and find something else. If you are FORCED to you can use a setTimeout or setInterval loop to monitor something (a variable, a div, an input etc.) for changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TLDR: Abandon the code.

All async functions in javascript either return a promise or accept a callback. This has been the culture in javascript since the mid 2000s. If you ever encounter the situation in your question the **best** solution is to not use that library and find something else.

### Workaround..

However, there are times when you need to do something like this. For example if you develop a mashup script that can be inserted by the user into his HTML and you have no control how the user copy/paste your code.

One workaround is to use `setTimeout` or `setInterval` to monitor something for change. This can be a variable, a `<div>`, an `<input>` etc. Here's a silly example that waits for `jQuery` to load:

```
const funcB = () => {
    console.log("second");
}

function waitForJQuery () {
    if (window.jQuery || window.$) { // check if jQuery variable exist
        console.log('jQuery loaded');
        funcB();
    }
    else {
        setTimeout(waitForJQuery, 200); // check 5 times per second
    }
}

waitForJQuery();
```

Normally you would not write code like this. But **IF** and only if you have no other choice you can do something like this.

Note though that this requires whatever you are waiting for to generate a side effect: either creating a global variable or modifying a global variable or updating the DOM etc.